# C# get Files from directory with specific CreationTime

Tags: c#, linq, file, date, path

i am writing a short code to move files from one directory to another. My code is simple, working fine and looks like this:

```
public void copy()
{
     string sourcePath = @"/Users/philip/Desktop/start";                                   
     string destinationPath = @"/Users/philip/Desktop/Ziel";                            

     string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath)               
            
     foreach (string s in files)                                                 
     {
          string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);                               
          string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, fileName);
          System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
     }
}
```

The Programm gets all files from the sourcepath and combines the targetpath in the foreach loop vor every file, containing of target path and filename. Then it moves it. Everything works fine.

My aim is now, not to store all files from my directory into the string array. I only want to get the files that have CreationTime after 01.07.2021. Is there an easy and quick way to do it?

I already used this to get the files, but it specifies a singular date and not all files after a specific date:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath).Where(x => new FileInfo(x).CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date);
```

I would be glad if you could help me out.

Best regards,
Liam

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_greaterthanorequal?view=net-5.0

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. That would be an option but I have over 100.000 files in a directory and every files is going to be checked to some conditions in the foreach loop. So I would like to filter those 100.000 files before checking them all to make the code more efficient.

Comment: You *could* order them by date descending before checking them, plus I'd also recommend you create a [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-5.0) and then use [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=net-5.0) so you can avoid creating the `FileInfo`

Comment: You say "but it specifies a singular date" and that indeed matches the `==` used. Have you tried `new FileInfo(x).CreationTime.Date > your_desired_date` ?

Comment: 100000 files with Directory.GetFiles? Look at Directory.EnumerateFiles and why is better when there are many files to process.

Comment: @Steve Thank you for your suggestion, I did not knew this Method yet because I am relatively new to C#. But I will implement it in my code for better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid having to check the creation date on every single `FileInfo` you can order your files. Like so:

```cs
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
var fileInfos = directory.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(fileInfo => fileInfo.CreationDate);

var result = new List<FileInfo>();

foreach (var fileInfo in fileInfos)
{
    if (fileInfo.CreationDate >= DateTime.Today)
        result.Add(fileInfo);
    else
        break; // We can break early, because we ordered our dates descending
               // meaning every date after this one is smaller
}
```

This has upsides and downsides, ordering a huge collection of files could take longer than "just" simply iterating over all and comparing the dates, but you'll need to benchmark it on your own

Comment: Ok thank you for the information. This is what I was looking for. I will benchmark it and going to check which method is better for performance.

Comment: That is much slower than just checking the value. It does N-1 compare and then you iterate on minimum of 1 items so N and this is the best case scenario so it N to 2N. Checking all of them is N no matter what.

Comment: @Franck Yes that's true, makes sense. I implemented it by checking the value. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-5.0)

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new(s);

if (fileInfo.CreationTime >= DateTime.Parse("01/07/2021"))
{
  ...
}
```